# Chart is not defined; please fix or add /*global chart*/ cloud9 chart.js javaScript

Tags: javascript, chart.js, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I got this error while I was working in cloud9 with JavaScript. How can I fix this?

[Chart is not defined; please fix or add /*global chart*/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mvVt.png)

Comment: I used to work in NetBeans IDE with PHP. I want to migrate my website to NodeJS frame, so I transferred all the files to aws-Cloud9. It worked on NetBeans but the same javaScript file doesn't work in Cloud9.

Comment: from the image you posted, it looks like the definition of `Chart` is missing. Maybe you forgot to import or add a reference to a certain library?

Comment: How do I import library in javaScript file?  For instance in C++  #include <iostream>

Comment: If you have an HTML file that has a tag `<script>` with a `src` that points to the library that has the definition of `Chart` then you can ignore that warning, since the IDE might not know where the definition is at design time. but at runtime things will be clear.

Comment: I see.  I wrote   import {Chart} from 'chart.js/Chart.js';  at the top of the JavaScript file and it removed the error message. It's not working yet but one step ahead. Thanks for the insight